# UINavigationBar : Add SearchBar as TitleView

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

I want to add uisearchbar in place of title of controller.

I am facing 2 problems currently.

1) 
I do not know from where this gray background is coming. Please check this picture. [image]

2) I need this searchbar in other inner screens also. But when I push another controller this searchbar is removed.

Here is my code :

```
// Seachbar Container View
    let searchBarContainer = ERView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,280,44))
    searchBarContainer.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth]
    searchBarContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

// Search Bar
    let searchBar = ERSearchBar(frame: searchBarContainer.bounds)
    searchBarContainer.addSubview(searchBar)

// Add View as Title View in Navigation Bar
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = searchBarContainer
```

Here is Code of my UISearchBar Class

```
 func commonInit() -> Void {
    // Update UI

    if let searchField = self.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField{
        // To change background color
        searchField.backgroundColor = UIColor.appNavigationBarDarkRedColor()

        // Tint Color
        if let leftViewRef = searchField.leftView {
            leftViewRef.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }else if let imgLeftView = searchField.leftView as? UIImageView{
            imgLeftView.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }

        // Font Color
        searchField.font = UIFont.robotoRegularFont(WithSize: 14.0)

        // Text Color
        searchField.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        // PlaceHolder Attributes
        searchField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()])
    }

    self.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_search_white"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search, state: UIControlState.Normal)
    // To change placeholder text color
}
```

Please someone help me here.

Answer (score 0):

For 1) Set the searchBarStyle property to minimal. This will provides no default background color in UIsearchBar.

2)I'm not quite sure what'd you mean by "inner screen". But if what you want is a Search Bar that can work across different view controllers, UISearchController is the one you're looking for.
You can fine the Apple sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html)